# PHP php_mongodb.dll for 32bit

Tags: php, mongodb, windows, installation, 32-bit

facing the error that my windows server 2019 uses 32bit. now i want to connect from that server with php to my mongodb. I've searched the whole internet for a 32bit version of the php_mongodb.dll but didn't found anything. Please help me!

I've tried to install pecl or pear but both didn't work. Even ChatGPT says I'm hopeless.

PS: PHP-Version: 8.2.0 & Webserver: IIS

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does windows server 2019 even exist as 32bit version? Install 64bit version of php - we are in 2024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all official MongoDB PHP Drivers on [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases).

Make sure you check first the [MongoDB compatibility table](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php-drivers/#compatibility) to download the appropriate `ext+lib` version.

Comment: I've tried to download the correct driver. There's nothing in the error log, but when I do:
`print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` on my PHP-Site, mongodb won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm very lost.

My Problem was that I've installed the wrong mongodb extension. I've thought that my php version is threaded safe but it was not.

So now I've installed the right php extension and using composer the right library.

Big thank to these two guys, which wanted to help me.